# How can a patent so broad be accepted?

Tags: usd679716

I'm intriguid as to how a patent so broad as this can be.  This is a very generic method of holding an object and seems to have not invention, why is this patent here?

Can anyone enlighten me, I feel I don't understand the process or maybe I'm not reading it correct, however, the limited description of anything specific in the concept tells me there is nothing here to protect.

I'm sorry if I seem naive, I am open to sensible explanations.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you normaly think of as a patent. It is a **design patent**. Design patents, unlike the better known **utility patents**, do *not* protect functionality. Design patents only protect the *look* of an item.

[image]